# How to get nodes where his child node has some value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have below xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Some Title</title>
            </wp:comment>
                <wp:comment_approved><![CDATA[1]]></wp:comment_approved>
            </wp:comment>
            </wp:comment>
                <wp:comment_approved><![CDATA[1]]></wp:comment_approved>
            </wp:comment>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I can easily get all wp:comments by:

```
xmlNode.SelectNodes("*[name()='wp:comment']")
```

But how can I get all wp:comments where wp:comment_approved has value 1?

Comment: Your sample xml is invalid, at some places the / before `wp:comment` is too much.

Answer (score 1):

it's updated @Stefan Hegny answer, as you need not `comment_approved`element, but `wp:comment`

```
xmlNode.SelectNodes("//*[name()='wp:comment'][./*[local-name() = 'comment_approved' and . = '1']")
```

i'm not sure if default css locators working here, but in common css xPath i'll use this locator (logic is simple - you seach some element, that contains element with special parameter, so you can adjust this locator to your needs):

```
//someTag[./innerTag[text() = '1']]
```